# Xcode simulator doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I use Xcode 7.2. I click Build to run the iPhone 6 PLUS simulator in Xcode it tells me "running app on iPhone 6 Plus". The simulator icon appears and it either just jumps up and down and never stops. Or it stops jumping I open it it's a black simulator screen with a white apple symbol. Then I wait 5-10 minutes and it never loads the app. Sometimes it loads up to home screen in simulator but then again never loads the app.

What could be the reasons for this iPhone simulator not working?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the simulator open from a beta version?  That will stop the simulator from working in a non-beta version (or vice-versa).

I'd also open up Console.app and see if there is anything in the logs with a reason why it might not be running.